# How to zoom in on off-center points with MacBook Pro mousepad?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut, osx

MacBook Pro here. Magic Mouse doesn't seem to help me with zooming on stuff inside of Blender, but I can zoom by gesturing the "[*two finger pinch-out*](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204895)" expression on the mouse pad.

---

I start Blender with a clean slate:

[image]

I create a shape (in this particular case, a Cone):

[image]

I move the Cone off-center somewhere:

[image]

Now I want to zoom in on the Cone (even with it being off-center). I do the zoom in gesture, but:

[image]

...Blender just wants me to zoom in on the origin (0,0,0).

**How do I zoom in on the Cone? (Or rather, how do I zoom in on off-center objects/points)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the `Zoom To Mouse` Setting as shown below:

[image]